# SHA1 in Haskell -- something wrong with my implementation

Tags: haskell, sha1

Thought I'd try to implement [SHA1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-1) in Haskell myself. I came up with an implementation that compiles and returns the right answer for the null string (""), but nothing else. I can't figure out what might be wrong. Can someone familiar with the algorithm and SHA1 point it out?

```
import Data.Bits
import Data.Int
import Data.List
import Data.Word
import Text.Printf
import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy as L
import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy.Char8 as C

h0 = 0x67452301 :: Word32
h1 = 0xEFCDAB89 :: Word32
h2 = 0x98BADCFE :: Word32
h3 = 0x10325476 :: Word32
h4 = 0xC3D2E1F0 :: Word32

sha1string :: String -> String
sha1string s = concat $ map (printf "%02x") $ sha1 . C.pack $ s 

sha1 :: L.ByteString -> [Word8]
sha1 msg = concat [w32ToComps a, w32ToComps b, w32ToComps c, w32ToComps d, w32ToComps e]
    where (a, b, c, d, e) = sha1' msg 0 h0 h1 h2 h3 h4 

sha1' msg sz a b c d e 
    | L.length m1 < 64 = sha1'last (padded msg sz) a b c d e
    | otherwise        = uncurry5 (sha1' m2 (sz + 64)) $ whole a b c d e m1
    where (m1, m2) = L.splitAt 64 msg

sha1'last msg a b c d e
    | m1 == L.empty = (a, b, c, d, e)
    | otherwise     = uncurry5 (sha1'last m2) $ whole a b c d e m1
    where (m1, m2) = L.splitAt 64 msg

whole a b c d e msg = partcd (partab msg) a b c d e 

partcd ws a b c d e = (h0 + a', h1 + b', h2 + c', h3 + d', h4 + e')
    where
    (a', b', c', d', e')  = go ws a b c d e 0
    go ws a b c d e 80    = (a, b, c, d, e)
    go (w:ws) a b c d e t = go ws temp a (rotate b 30) c d (t+1)
        where temp = (rotate a 5) + f t b c d + e + w + k t

partab chunk = take 80 ns
    where
    ns        = initial ++ zipWith4 g (drop 13 ns) (drop 8 ns) (drop 2 ns) ns
    g a b c d = rotate (a `xor` b `xor` c `xor` d) 1
    initial   = map (L.foldl (\a b -> (a * 256) + fromIntegral b) 0) $ paginate 4 chunk

f t b c d
    | t >=  0 && t <= 19 = (b .&. c) .|. ((complement b) .&. d)
    | t >= 20 && t <= 39 = b `xor` c `xor` d
    | t >= 40 && t <= 59 = (b .&. c) .|. (b .&. d) .|. (c .&. d)
    | t >= 60 && t <= 79 = b `xor` c `xor` d

k t
    | t >=  0 && t <= 19 = 0x5A827999
    | t >= 20 && t <= 39 = 0x6ED9EBA1
    | t >= 40 && t <= 59 = 0x8F1BBCDC
    | t >= 60 && t <= 79 = 0xCA62C1D6

padded msg prevsz = L.append msg (L.pack pad)
    where
    sz      = L.length msg
    totalsz = prevsz + sz
    padsz   = fromIntegral $ (128 - 9 - sz) `mod` 64
    pad     = [0x80] ++ (replicate padsz 0) ++ int64ToComps totalsz

uncurry5 f (a, b, c, d, e) = f a b c d e

paginate n xs
    | xs == L.empty = []
    | otherwise     = let (a, b) = L.splitAt n xs in a : paginate n b

w32ToComps :: Word32 -> [Word8]
w32ToComps = integerToComps [24, 16 .. 0] 

int64ToComps :: Int64 -> [Word8]
int64ToComps = integerToComps [56, 48 .. 0] 

integerToComps :: (Integral a, Bits a) => [Int] -> a -> [Word8]
integerToComps bits x = map f bits
    where f n = fromIntegral ((x `shiftR` n) .&. 0xff) :: Word8
```

Comment: When debugging, it's very helpful if you can narrow down the problem to the function deepest in the call stack that does something unexpected. Can you try to make a few calls to the other functions in ghci and verify that they are computing what you expect them to compute?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For starters, you appear to be keeping a size count in bytes (see `sz + 64`), but the count that gets appended should be in bits so you need to multiply by 8 somewhere (incidentally, I suggest you use `cereal` or `binary` instead of rolling your own Integer to big endian Word64).  This isn't the only problem though.

**EDIT: Found It**

Ah-ha!  Never forget, wikipedia is written by a bunch of imperative, mutable-world unenlighteneds!  You finish each chunk with `h0 + a', h1 + b', ...` but that should be the old context plus your new values: `a + a', b + b', ...`.  Everything checks out after that (and the above size) fix.

The test code completes now with 5 property tests and 129 KATs succeeding.

**End Edit**

It would help you out a lot if you divided your implementation into the normal initial, update, finalize operations.  That way you could compare intermediate results with other implementations.

I just built test code for your implementation using `crypto-api-tests`.  The additional code is below if you're interested, don't forget to install `crypto-api-tests`.

```
import Test.SHA
import Test.Crypto
import Crypto.Classes
import Data.Serialize
import Data.Tagged
import Control.Monad

main = defaultMain =<< makeSHA1Tests (undefined :: SHA1)

data SHA1 = SHA1 [Word8]
  deriving (Eq, Ord, Show)
data CTX = CTX L.ByteString
instance Serialize SHA1 where
  get = liftM SHA1 (mapM (const get) [1..20])
  put (SHA1 x) = mapM_ put x

instance Hash CTX SHA1 where
  outputLength = Tagged 160
  blockLength  = Tagged (64*8)
  initialCtx   = CTX L.empty
  updateCtx   (CTX m) x = CTX (L.append m (L.fromChunks [x]))
  finalize  (CTX m) b = SHA1 $ sha1 (L.append m (L.fromChunks [b]))
```

Comment: That's incredible, Thomas. Thank you very much :)